# Importing SciPy does not work

Tags: python, ubuntu, scipy

I am trying to use SciPy to solve a very simple equation (Kepler's equation) using Newton-Raphson. However, exectuing the program fails with the following error message:

```
    return sc.optimize.newton(f, meanAnomaly, f_prime, args=(), 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'newton'
```

Clearly though, I have SciPy installed under Ubuntu 12.04. From scipy.test():

```
NumPy version 1.5.1
NumPy is installed in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy
SciPy version 0.9.0
SciPy is installed in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy
Python version 2.7.2+ (default, Jan 21 2012, 23:31:34) [GCC 4.6.2]
nose version 1.1.2
```

What is wrong? Here is my code:

```
# File a
from b import *

print calculate_eccentric_anomaly(1,2)

# File b
def calculate_eccentric_anomaly(meanAnomaly, eccentricity):
    import scipy.optimize as sc

    def f(eccentricAnomaly):
        return (eccentricAnomaly - eccentricity * 
                sc.sin(eccentricAnomaly) - meanAnomaly)

    def f_prime(eccentricAnomaly):
        return 1 - eccentricity * sc.cos(eccentricAnomaly)

    return sc.optimize.newton(f, meanAnomaly, f_prime, args=(), 
                              tol=1e-10, maxiter=50)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're importing `scipy.optimize` as `sc`, then you're trying to call `sc.optimize.newton`, which would effectively be `scipy.optimize.optimize.newton`. I would do

```
import scipy.optimize as opt
```

or

```
import scipy.optimize as scopt
```

Answer (score 0):

You've probably figured this out too, but in addition to the problem larsmans points out, there is no sin/cos in scipy.optimize.

Comment: Indeed that is true. Figured it out myself by now, but thanks for your remark anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I mostly added that for the benefit of anyone who comes here via search engine.